# How to use npm install on an SSH machine in GitHub Actions

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions

How to use npm install on an SSH machine in GitHub Actions

Hello, I am trying to access, clone a repo, and execute the npm install from the repo on an SSH machine. For this, I have the following code:

```
name: SSH Git Clone

# on:
#   workflow_dispatch:

on: [push]

jobs:
  ssh-git-clone:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Create file on SSH server
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: '${{ secrets.SSH_HOST_DEV }}'
          username: '${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME_DEV }}'
          password: '${{ secrets.SSH_PASSWORD_DEV }}'
          port: '${{ secrets.SSH_PORT_DEV }}'
          script: |

            curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
            nvm install node 16.19.0

            REPO_DIR="/home/dev/backend"
  



            eval `ssh-agent -s`
            ssh-add - <<< '${{ secrets.SSH_CLONE_KEY }}'
            rm -rf "$REPO_DIR"
            git clone ${{ github.event.repository.ssh_url }} "$REPO_DIR"
            cd "$REPO_DIR"
            
            npm install
```

Even though it detects that nvm is already installed on the machine, it does not allow me to use node or install anything. Is there any way to accomplish this?

## EDIT

It's like there was a confusion between the dependencies of runs-on and those of ssh.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly I found this: https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/issues/21

script: |
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
npm --help

That worked